# Unusual JSON after passing an Enum using Thymeleaf with spring model

Tags: json, spring-boot, enums, spring-data, thymeleaf

This is my object Policy, which has an Enum "effect"

```
@Entity
public class Policy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="effect")
    private Effect effect;

    public Policy() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Effect getEffect() {
        return effect;
    }

    public void setEffect(Effect effect) {
        this.effect = effect;
    }
```

This is what that Enum Effect looks like:

```
public enum Effect {
    allow,
    deny
}
```

This is my Controller that passes that Enum "effect" with spring model

```
@RequestMapping("/modifyPolicy/{id}")
public String modifyPolicy(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("enumEffect", policyService.getPolicy(id).getEffect());
    return "modifyPolicy";
}
```

I access the Enum "effect" by seting up a JavaScript variable by using Thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html...>
...
...
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    ...

    var someEnum = /*[[${enumEffect}]]*/;
    alert(JSON.stringify(enumEffect));

    ...
     /*]]>*/
    </script>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this is delivering me following JSON which is unusual:

```
{"$type":"Effect","$name":"deny"}
```

I need to get a JSON like this, which should be the normal case:

```
{"Effect":"deny"}
```

How can I achieve this without **making it complicated with custom JsonSerializer or JsonDeserializer?** There needs to be a simple way...

Comment: If the default serialization is how you are seeing it now, then you got to build your own. Its pretty simple. At the server you can push a map: `map.put("Effect", policyService.getPolicy(id).getEffect().toString())` and use the map in the client.

Comment: Thanks, but what about if I have to Map the Object "Policy" which contains an Enum Effect. A Policy would look like this: { "id": 15", "effect": { "$type": "Effect", "$name": "deny" }} How can I easily map that?

Comment: No, If you serialize the `Policy` object then the `Effect` will be serialized by calling `toString()`

Comment: So whats the solution if I have a Policy that includes an Enum Effect?

Comment: I would suggest you to try serializing the `Policy` object to JSON. It should work without any issue.